# opening google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I open maps with GPS point here so:

```
 String geoUri = String.format("geo:%s,%s?z=15", Double.toString(lat), Double.toString(lng)); 
 Uri geo = Uri.parse(geoURI); 
 Intent geoMap = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geo); 
 startActivity(geoMap);
```

google is focused in the right place of a map, but the point was not set. What's missing from google maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `geo:0,0?q=lat,lng(label)`
Show the map at the `given longitude and latitude with a string label`.
Example: `"geo:0,0?q=34.99,-106.61"`

Sample code:

```
Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?").buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("q", Double.toString(lat), Double.toString(lng))
                .build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(geoLocation);

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // Error            
        }
```

For more details, please refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps).